# How get request parameter in Symfony Voter?

Tags: symfony

I set request_stack arguments

```
api.uid_voter:
    class: SecretBundle\Security\UidVoter
    arguments: ['@request_stack']
    tags:
        - { name: security.voter }
    public: false
```

# app/config/security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/secret, roles: [UID] }
```

Next I trying in Voter

```
public function __construct(RequestStack $request_stack)
{
    $this->uid = $request_stack->getCurrentRequest()->get('uid');
}
```

And

> Call to a member function get() on null

But, if *$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('UID')* from controller - with no error

Comment: I need simple  compare UID from url with authorized user ID in token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual request is not available when the service itself is created.  You need to get the uid when you actually need it.  Something like:

```
class MyVoter {
    private $requestStack;
    public function __construct($requestStack) {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }
    private function getUid() {
        return  $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->get('uid');
```